# Finding out if a class has a class initializer without reading the class file

Tags: java, class, typeinitializer

I wonder if there is a known way of finding out if a loaded `Class` has a class initializer, i.e. is compiled with a `<clinit>` method. I know that this method is not visible or invokable via reflection but I want to copy a loaded class while applying some transformations.

I would like to avoid the parsing of the class file because I redefine all methods of this class, which effectively means that I do not need any information from the file as all information that is relevant to me is available from the loaded `Class`.

Thus my question: Is it possible to check a loaded `Class` for the existence of a class initializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending quite some efforts on digging through this and reading up on the web: The `ClassLoader` subsystem does not expose this information to the `Class` representation. Any method information is retrieved from a native call which is already filtering away the `<clinit>` method. On the JVM runtime side of things, there is only internal exposure, which can be used as a non-canonical way of finding out. For this puprpse, the `ObjectStreamClass` defines a static, private method `hasStaticInitializer(Class)` which is used to compute an implicit serialization UID which is rehashed by the UTF value of `<clinit>()V` and `Modifier.STATIC` only if a class has a class initializer.

This coincidence can however be used to create a canonical way which does not use internal methods: By computing the implicit serial ID manually one can narrow this value down to two values, one value for a version of a `Class` with a class initializer and one value for the same `Class` without such an initializer. One can then additionally serialize the class literal and see what value the serialization engine returns. If this value represents the value that was rehashed by `<clinit>()V`, one knows that the class defines such a method. Otherwise, it does not have such a value.